# Regular expression with conditional extraction

Tags: java, regex

I have sentences like

```
1 1994 FORD 5640 2WD Tractor

2 AG-GATOR 1004 4x4 Tree Spade Truck

3 2004 ROSCO RB48 Broom

4 TENNANT 830II Street Sweeper
```

from which i need to extract words using regex like

```
5640
1004
RB48
830II
```

i.e.in a sentance if there is a year such as 1994 in 1st sentance i need to get the 4th word(5640) if there is no year  like 2nd sentence i need to get the 3rd word(1004)

Can anyone suggest me a regular expression to achieve this ???..

Comment: Maybe [`^(?:(?=(?:19|20)\d{2}\s|\S+\s+(?:19|20)\d{2}\s|\S+\s+\S+\s+(?:19|20)\d{2}\s)\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)|\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+))`](https://regex101.com/r/zV3zK9/1), but in your case, I would not use a regex of that complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex

```
\d+\s(?:\d{4}\s\S*?\s(\S+)|\S+\s(\S+))
```

**[Test regex here](https://regex101.com/r/rV2iS1/2)**

1. `\d+` for index number
2. `\d{4}\s\S*?\s(\S+)` for first type
3. `\S+\s(\S+)` for matching

**Update :** For index with alphanueric use

```
(?<=^|\n)\w+\s(?:\d{4}\s\S*?\s(\S+)|\S+\s(\S+))
```

**[Test regex here](https://regex101.com/r/rV2iS1/4)**

Use `(?<=^|\n)`, positive look behind for string should be either at the beginning or after a newline

Comment: Didn't know about that regex101 website, thanks for sharing.

Comment: but the above regex doesn't work
"4A 1998 BROCE RJ350 Broom"
sentance

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran You didn't specify that the first field could be alphanumeric. Then replace `\d+` with `\S+`, so `\b\S+\s(?:\d{4}\s\S*?\s(\S+)|\S+\s(\S+))\b`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the layout is somewhat constant (as it seems from your question) just make the year optional:

```
^\d+ (?:\d{4} )?\S+ (\S+)
```

Breakdown of the expression:

- `^` start of the input
- `\d+` a sequence of digits followed by a space char
- `(?:\d{4} )?` on optional sequence of 4 digits followed by a space char
- `\S+` a sequence of non-whitespace followed by a space char
- `(\S+)` a sequence of non-whitespace as a capturing group - this is what you're after

If you want to support any whitespace in between and possibly any length use `\s+` instead of just the space character.

Use classes `Pattern` and `Matcher` to apply the regex on each sentence and use `group(1)` on the matcher to extract the content of the group you're looking for.

**Edit:** note that `\d` will match any kind of digit. If you want to only allow ascii digits 0-9 use `[0-9]` instead.

Depending on how much you want to restrict possible year numbers you might want to expand that expression as well, e.g. `(19|20)[0-9]{2}` instead of `\d{4}`.

Answer (score 0):

What about `/\d{4}(?!.*\d{4})/g`? Use a negative lookahead to skip characters without matching.

EDIT: this regex matches the last 4 digit sequence in the text.

Comment: I was just showing how to use a negative lookahead. I'm not going to spoil the fun of creating the regex yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
(?=^(?:.*\d{4}\s)?[-a-zA-Z]+\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wS5vU7/1)

Which means:

- `(?=` - positive lookahead for:
- `^` - beginning of a line,
- `(?:.*\d{4}\s)?` - four digits and space,
- `[-a-zA-Z]+\s` - one or more letters and a spece,
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - one or more letters or digits (desired value)

This regex match by grouping in lookahead, so it will not match any text, just zero-lenght point in text, but you can get values by `group(1)`. Example in Java:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] array = {"1994 FORD 5640 2WD Tractor","AG-GATOR 1004 4x4 Tree Spade Truck","2004 ROSCO RB48 Broom",
                "TENNANT 830II Street Sweeper","4A 1998 BROCE RJ350 Broom"};
        Matcher matcher = null;
        for(String element : array) {
            matcher = Pattern.compile("(?=^(?:.*\\d{4}\\s)?[-a-zA-Z]+\\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+))").matcher(element);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another way, but only for Java, would be to match directly with:

```
(?<=^(?:.{0,99}\d{4}\s)?[-a-zA-Z]{1,99}\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

[DEMO](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiLqrQYDA/index.html)

this is using positive lookbehind without fixed lenght. It use rather ugly construction with syntax like: `.{0,99}` (from zero to 99 characters), etc. In most regex flavour you cannot use quantifires in lookbehinds, but Java allow usage of `?` and intervals with min and max values (`{2,6}`). It is not too elegant, but works in this case.